# Why I am unable to access service created by docker-compose?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I am building a micro-service based web app with `Flask` and `Docker`. Currently, I have 2 services running by `docker-compose` under the same default network.

- mysql
- product_api

**docker-compose.yml** file is --

```
version: '3'

services:
  mysql:
    image: mysql
    environment:
      MYSQL_USER: "mysqluser"
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: "mysqlpassword"
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: "root"
      MYSQL_DATABASE: "gadgetfreeiot"
    container_name: mysql
    ports:
      - 3306:3306
    restart: always
    entrypoint: ['docker-entrypoint.sh', '--default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password']

  product_api:
    build: ./${SERVICE_ROOT:-src/services/product/api}
    image: product_api:v1
    container_name: product_api
    volumes: 
      - ./${SERVICE_ROOT:-src/services/product/api}:${PROJECT_ROOT:-/usr/projects/gadgetfreeiot}/${SERVICE_ROOT:-src/services/product/api}
    ports: 
      - 5000:5000
    depends_on:
      - mysql
    environment:
      username: "mysqluser"
      password: "mysqlpassword"
      host: "mysql"
      port: "3306"
      database: "gadgetfreeiot"
    command: ["./wait-for-mysql.sh", "--", "python", "./run.py"]
```

`docker ps` output gives me --

```
johir@ubuntu:gadgetfreeiot$ docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                               NAMES
e10329e26e5c        product_api:v1      "./wait-for-mysql.sh…"   18 minutes ago      Up 18 minutes       0.0.0.0:5000->5000/tcp              product_api
7fed5a136123        mysql               "docker-entrypoint.s…"   18 minutes ago      Up 18 minutes       0.0.0.0:3306->3306/tcp, 33060/tcp   mysql
```

Both services are running under `gadgetfreeiot_default` network. `docker inspect gadgetfreeiot_default` shows that both are under the same network --

```
johir@ubuntu:gadgetfreeiot$ docker inspect gadgetfreeiot_default 
[
    {
        "Name": "gadgetfreeiot_default",
        "Id": "67e09ae3a33c0ff4203eefe4fee6ba421d3f68564c6e32c7d1cd04e866ac6850",
        "Created": "2018-10-18T14:56:05.86215576+03:00",


       "Scope": "local",
        "Driver": "bridge",
        "EnableIPv6": false,
        "IPAM": {
            "Driver": "default",
            "Options": null,
            "Config": [
                {
                    "Subnet": "192.168.0.0/20",
                    "Gateway": "192.168.0.1"
                }
            ]
        },
        "Internal": false,
        "Attachable": true,
        "Ingress": false,
        "ConfigFrom": {
            "Network": ""
        },
        "ConfigOnly": false,
        "Containers": {
            "14ffb8eaa0c17de0122de142dbcf7aa5455b41b47eadb197e8be200c2375fbb3": {
                "Name": "mysql",
                "EndpointID": "38ed4140ed728271194ee82f12b3d937c53166f6159ab4e6fcf2d8087039ed06",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:c0:a8:00:02",
                "IPv4Address": "192.168.0.2/20",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            },
            "e013059b510e42933d33f7c3fb7e141a19a6c78a0e34d031e5fce5e104aa8697": {
                "Name": "product_api",
                "EndpointID": "fdbe0ed92d0e53d6fc1040a50b1898e2bb87b34384f80b98e638a3a89a57c4e1",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:c0:a8:00:03",
                "IPv4Address": "192.168.0.3/20",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            }
        },
        "Options": {},
        "Labels": {
            "com.docker.compose.network": "default",
            "com.docker.compose.project": "gadgetfreeiot",
            "com.docker.compose.version": "1.22.0"
        }
    }
]
```

Now I am trying to access the `product_api` as well as `mysql` services from my host OS. In the meantime, I am also trying to access from one container to another (from `product_api` to `mysql` and from `mysql` to `product_api`). `mysql` is accessible from all 3 that is my host OS, product_api and mysql itself by --

```
mysql -h172.19.0.2 -P3306 -umysqluser -p
```

`product_api` is also able to access by --

```
mysql -hmysql -P3306 -umysqluser -p
```

Luckily I am able to access **`curl http://localhost:5000`** shows from **product_api** --

```
johir@ubuntu:gadgetfreeiot$ docker exec -it product_api bash
root@e013059b510e:/usr/projects/gadgetfreeiot/src/services/product/api# curl http://localhost:5000
{
  "message": "Endpoint not found", 
  "status": "failed"
}
```

Where **`curl http://172.19.0.3:5000`** shows --

```
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 172.19.0.3 port 5000: Connection refused
```

That means `product_api` is up & running and only accessible by `localhost` or `127.0.0.1` from inside the product_api container not by IP or by service name from outside product_api container that is neither from my host OS nor from `mysql` container.

Finally, I checked -- active networks among 3 by `netstat -tln` --

```
# product_api container 
root@e10329e26e5c:/usr/projects/gadgetfreeiot/src/services/product/api# netstat -tln
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State      
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.11:40071        0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:5000          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN

# mysql container
root@7fed5a136123:/# netstat -tln
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State      
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.11:35507        0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 :::33060                :::*                    LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 :::3306                 :::*                    LISTEN

# host OS
johir@ubuntu:gadgetfreeiot$ netstat -tln
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State      
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.53:53           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:631           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 ::1:631                 :::*                    LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 :::5000                 :::*                    LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 :::3306                 :::*                    LISTEN
```

**Note:**
port 5000 is not open by tcp6 in `product_api` container. On the other hand port 3306 is open by tcp6 on `mysql` container.

**Question:** Why I am unable to access `product_api` service from my host OS or even from mysql (in constraint, why tcp6 is not exposing port 5000 for product_api service)?

Comment: Can you access it from outside? I see you have mapped to the port outside. (not bash into the docker container)

Comment: Seeing the log output from your server would help immensely.  If you can't reach a container process from outside the container, a frequent cause is that it's set to listen on 127.0.0.1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer is, you aren't unable to access, as you showed with `curl http://localhost:5000`. It just seems to be a bit confusing who (host vs containers) can access which IPs and resolve which hostnames.

In your `docker-compose.yml` you mapped the ports `3306` and `5000` to your respective containers. So docker added a port forward from any interface on your host (w/o the interfaces of the docker networks) to your containers (have a look at the output of `sudo iptables-save | grep 5000` if you are interested in how it's done under the hood, it will look something like this:

```
-A DOCKER -d 192.168.0.2/20 ! -i br-e013059b510e -o br-e013059b510e -p tcp -m tcp --dport 5000 -j ACCEPT
```

### Access

So from your host, you can reach your service via

```
curl http://localhost:5000
```

From another computer (assuming firewall settings allow) via

```
curl http://your.hostname:5000
```

From a container on the same docker network

```
curl http://product_api:5000                            # or
curl http://product_api.gadgetfreeiot_default:5000      # or
curl http://192.168.0.3:5000
```

To have both container on the same docker network, adjust your `docker-compose.yml` like this:

```
services:
  mysql:
  [...]
  ports:
    - 3306:3306
  networks:
    - gadgetfreeiot
  [...]

  product_api:
    ports:
      - 5000:5000
    networks:
      - gadgetfreeiot
  [...]
networks:
  gadgetfreeiot:
```

### DNS

Container hostnames like `product_api` are not resolvable on the host. They are however inside your containers. Inside a container you have an extra docker DNS server at `127.0.0.11` which can resolve what your host can resove, plus docker hostnames like `product_api.gadgetfreeiot_default`. Try

```
nslookup product_api.gadgetfreeiot_default
```

on your host and from inside the container

```
docker exec -it mysql bash
```

Check https://docs.docker.com/network/ for more info on that.

With regards to your note: `netstat` doesn't show you which port is "open", i.e. allowed by the firewall, but which port is bound to by a program. Whether a program binds to a port on an interface on IPv4, v6 or both, is up to the program. This is not related to docker networking.

Comment: `product_api` is up & running and only accessible by `localhost` or `127.0.0.1` from inside the product_api container not by IP or by service name from outside product_api container that is neither from my host OS nor from `mysql` container.

Comment: I missed, that your `myspql` and `product_api` container are not on the same network, I expanded my answer to show, how you add them both to the same network.

Comment: Can you clarify the note section that I just figured out? @hjsimpson

Comment: `netstat` doesn't show you which port is "open", i.e. allowed by the firewall, but which port is bound to by a program. Whether a program binds to a port on an interface on IPv4, v6 or both, is up to the program.

Comment: I have done those before what you have suggested for `docker-compose.yml`.

Comment: Your `docker-compose.yml` doesn't show that. Start with a minimal example, maybe two container based on `ubuntu:18.04` and work your way forward.

Comment: The problem is not actually with the docker-compose.yml file but of course else. But anyway, your suggestions, enlight the way I should care about. I just change `app.run()` to `app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port='5000')` in the `run.py` script. Anyway thanks a lot.